# Use javascript to switch pages in acrobat reader in webbrowser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, acrobat

For a project I am looking for a good way to display pdf files in a webbrowser (IE8 and newer). The browsers used in my project have acrobat reader installed, so thatwillbe the preferred way to visualize thepdf file.

Is there a way to access acrobat reader currently opened in a div to (for instance) switch pages or jump to a given bookmark? Is it also possible to listen for text selection events?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This existing post can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733358/javascript-in-a-pdf

Comment: This is for javascripting inside a pdf. I'm more looking for using javascript to access the pdf embedded in a html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked on this problem for some time, I now use the following solution:

- Use pdfObject.js to embed the pdf file in my webpage.
- Communicate between pdf and html using the HostContainer. Important here is that you are able to put some javascript in the PDF file.
- Important note is that this only works with the embedded Acrobat Reader/Pro version.
- see: http://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=301)

Good luck. If you encounter problems, just leave a message, perhaps I can help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can control the PDF from the outside of the page. However, [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) is a PDF renderer written in Javascript. It allows you to embed a PDF viewer inside a page and fully control it, including flipping pages, and the like. It may just be what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks, I'll havea look at it.

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve all of your feature requests, but you may want to take a look at the [PDF open parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf). If you open a pdf with the appropriate hash-url, you can control reader's behavior.

For example, the following will open a PDF and go to the third page of the pdf:

```
http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3
```